# what is wrong here for plotting dos in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

My script:

```
set term postscript enhanced colour
set output 'dos.ps
set key  box font 'Helvetica, 12' left center
set key at 6,15
set grid
set size noratio 1, 0.8
set style fill transparent solid 1.0 noborder
set style data filledcurves y1=0
set arrow from 0, graph 0 to 0, graph 1 nohead
set xlabel "E-E_f [eV]" font 'Helvetica, 20'
set arrow 5 head filled size screen 0.02,13 from -0.5,-17.3 to 0.4,-17.3 lc rgb "black" lw 3
set arrow 6 head filled size screen 0.02,13 from -9.05,5.5 to -9.05,8.4 lc rgb "black" lw 3
set ylabel "Density of states" font 'Helvetica, 20'
plot [-5:3] [-10:10] 'dos.dat' using ($1-12.6258):2 with filledcu lc rgb "red" title "Spin Up",'dos.dat' using ($1-12.6258):($3*-1) with filledcu lc rgb "#4169E1" title "Spin Down",0.0 lc rgb "black" title '','dos.dat' with lines lc rgb "black" title ''
set output
! ps2pdf -r300 dos.ps
! rm dos.ps
! pdftocairo -png -r 300 dos.pdf
```

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Why are the curves not filled with the above script?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We don't have your data, so we cannot easily reproduce your script. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example We don't even know what your output is. Maybe none? We don't know. Please show (a graph) or describe in words what is going "wrong" or what is unexpected. By the way, why are you trying to create a .ps and converting it to .pdf instead of using gnuplot's pdfcairo terminal directly?

Comment: i want to plot dos.dat file of quantum espresso

Comment: Yes, I very much assume that you want to plot this file. But I don't have your data file, so I cannot reproduce your case. What is the final output file you would like to have? A .ps or .pdf or .png? "What's wrong?" or "Doesn't work!" is not very helpful for solving the problem. Please give more details. What is your output? What are the error or warning messages in case you get some?

Comment: E (eV)   dosup(E)     dosdw(E)   Int dos(E) EFermi =   12.625 eV
   0.000 -0.1385E-80 -0.1208E-80 -0.2593E-83
   0.001 -0.1385E-80 -0.1209E-80 -0.5186E-83
   0.002 -0.1385E-80 -0.1209E-80 -0.7780E-83
   0.003 -0.1385E-80 -0.1209E-80 -0.1037E-82
   0.004 -0.1385E-80 -0.1209E-80 -0.1297E-82
   0.005 -0.1385E-80 -0.1209E-80 -0.1556E-82
   0.006 -0.1386E-80 -0.1209E-80 -0.1816E-82
   0.007 -0.1386E-80 -0.1209E-80 -0.2075E-82
   0.008 -0.1386E-80 -0.1209E-80 -0.2335E-82
   0.009 -0.1386E-80 -0.1210E-80 -0.2594E-82
   ................

Comment: Please edit your question and add the data such that the actual format and structure can be seen. Comments are not suited for this.

Comment: can i connect with you through any other social media sir?

Comment: sri please give me your gmail id if you have so i can send you my data ??

Comment: I don't use "social" media... let's try this way... https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/249563/so74355087?tab=general

Comment: too bad, I guess you need at least 20 reputation to chat in a chat room. Let me know whether you can enter or not.

Comment: do you have gmail or outlook something so i can send you a image??

Comment: can you upload your image on https://imgur.com/ and post the link?

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/cVP7nDb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things in your script which I don't understand:

- why are you creating a postscript file which you later convert to PDF and then to PNG. Why not directly using terminal `pngcairo`?
- `set key at 6,15` is outside the graph
- `set size noratio 1, 0.8` What's the purpose of this?
- `set style data filledcurves y1=0`   (haven't seen/used this so far)
- arrows 5 and 6 are outside the graph
- `... 0.0 lc rgb "black" title ''` Plot the x-axis again?
- `...'dos.dat' with lines lc rgb "black" ...` Plot a black outline again?

Check the following minimized script as starting point. You posted only data as image which doesn't help too much. So, I used some data.

**Data:**  `SO74355087.dat`

```
 7.0   1.0   1.0
 7.5   0.1   1.0
 8.0   3.0   4.0
 8.5   4.0   3.0
 9.0   0.5   2.0
 9.5   7.0   5.0
10.0   4.0   7.0
10.5   1.0   1.0
11.0   0.0   2.0
11.5   9.0   3.0
12.0   0.0   0.0
12.5   3.0   0.0
13.0   2.5   0.0
13.5   2.0   0.0
14.0   1.0   5.0
14.5   1.0   3.0
15.0   0.5   1.0
15.5   0.0   0.5
```

**Script:**

```
### plot with filledcurves
reset session

FILE = "SO74355087.dat"

set key box font 'Helvetica, 12' top right noautotitle
set grid
set style fill transparent solid 1.0 noborder

set xlabel "E-E_f [eV]" font 'Helvetica, 20'
set ylabel "Density of states" font 'Helvetica, 20'
set xzeroaxis

set xrange[-5:3]
set yrange[-10:10]

set term pngcairo size 640,384
set output "SO74355087.png"

plot FILE u ($1-12.6258):2    w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "red"     ti "Spin Up", \
      '' u ($1-12.6258):(-$3) w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "#4169E1" ti "Spin Down"

set output
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Ok, you want to smooth the curve. Check `help smooth`. There are different options: e.g. `bezier`, `splines`, `kdensity`. Depending on what data you have and what you want to see (how smooth) you need to play with these options.

For the script above, if you use the same data but change the plotting lines to:

```
plot $Data u ($1-12.6258):2   smooth cspline w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "red"     ti "Spin Up", \
      '' u ($1-12.6258):(-$3) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.2 w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "#4169E1" ti "Spin Down"
```

You will get the following. Please read `help smooth` for getting a deeper understanding.

[image]

**Addition:** smoothing options

Please read `help smooth` and play with the numbers `set sample 500` and if you use `smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.02`.

**Script:**

```
### plot with filledcurves
reset session

FILE = "SO74355087.dat"
FILE = "dos.dat"

set key box font 'Helvetica, 12' top right noautotitle
set grid
set style fill transparent solid 1.0 noborder
set style data filledcurves y1=0

set xlabel "E-E_f [eV]" font 'Helvetica, 20'
set ylabel "Density of states" font 'Helvetica, 20'
set xzeroaxis

set xrange[-5:3]
set yrange[*:*]

set term pngcairo size 640,900
set output "SO74355087.png"

set samples 500

set multiplot layout 3,1

    plot FILE u ($1-12.6258):2  w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "red"     ti "Spin Up", \
        '' u ($1-12.6258):(-$3) w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "#4169E1" ti "Spin Down"

    plot FILE u ($1-12.6258):2  smooth bezier w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "red"     ti "Spin Up", \
        '' u ($1-12.6258):(-$3) smooth bezier w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "#4169E1" ti "Spin Down"

    plot FILE u ($1-12.6258):2  smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.02 w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "red"     ti "Spin Up", \
        '' u ($1-12.6258):(-$3) smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.02 w filledcurves y=0 lc rgb "#4169E1" ti "Spin Down"

unset multiplot
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:**

*Top graph:* original data as is

*Middle graph:* `smooth bezier`

*Bottom graph:* `smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.02`

You might want to scale the y-values... or remove ytics to have arbitraty units...

[image]

Comment: i used the above script but it doesnt work sir?

Comment: i want both png and pdf format sir ??1 png and 1 pdf format

Comment: https://imgur.com/gallery/6cR69I3

Comment: @BinayLimbu if the linked image is not what you expect, what is it then? What do you expect?

Comment: i expect same curve but smooth without the edges as i send in previous link sir

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOSF4.png like this sir i want my final output

Comment: sir i cannot send in your id?

Comment: @BinayLimbu try to use for example www.pastebin.com to provide your data.

Comment: sir can you check my data and send me a correct script ??i have sent you twice

Comment: @BinayLimbu you could simply split the file into two parts.

Comment: @BinayLimbu ok, finally :-)   Check my modified answer. Please delete your comments above which are not essential to the question to clean this up a little. Thanks.

Comment: thank you sir it works but why my yrange is like 15000 it should have to be like 10 
may be its due to smooth kdensity bandwidth 0.02

Comment: @BinayLimbu yes, please read the documentation `help smooth kdensity`! It sums up many gaussian distributions. You have to scale it by some number which also will depend on the bandwidth value.

Comment: thank you sir for your attention and goodwill i hope you you will help me in the future too
god bless you sir

Comment: @BinayLimbu if the answer solved your problem please check the checkmark at the top left of the answer indicating that the question is answered. Well, next time, please with complete and minimized example and a clear description what you have as input, what you tried, what you got and what the problem or goal is, "what is wrong here" is not a good and descriptive title. So, you actually wanted to fill your curve _and_ smooth your data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74471162/how-to-plot-partial-density-of-states-in-gnuplot

Comment: sir i have again another problem ?i got stuck again

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1UwQqHhQMSjBnXBTwu3YlgZAb-IY0wLmn?usp=share_link