# How to plot partial density of states in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I tried to plot using this script but it doesnt work well.

```
set term postscript enhanced colour
set output 'pdos.ps'
set key box font 'Helvetica, 12' top right noautotitle
set grid
set xlabel "E-E_f [eV]" font 'Helvetica, 20'
set ylabel "PDos(states/ev)" font 'Helvetica, 20'
set xzeroaxis
set xrange[-6:4]
set yrange[*:*]
plot 'Co_d.dat' u 1:2 w l lc "green", 'Mn_d.dat' u 1:2 w l lc "red', 'Sb_p.dat' u 1:2 w l lc "#4169E1"
set output
```

I expect this like this plot as in this image I mentioned.

[image]

I got image like this.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the way how StackOverflow works. What have you tried so far? On StackOverflow it is expected that you show some own research effort. This seems to be a very basic plotting task which probably every basic gnuplot tutorial in the web will cover. SO is for everything which is non-standard and non-obvious. Have you consulted a tutorial, the gnuplot homepage or the manual? Something like `plot 'file1.dat' u 1:2 w l lc "green", 'file2.dat' u 1:2 w l lc "red', 'file3.dat' u 1:2 w l lc "blue"`. Please show your script, the resulting graph and describe what the problem is.

Comment: sir i have edit my mistake but still i have no much idea about proper gnuplot and have very less duration for project work.so i have not gone through gnuplot documentation

Comment: Again, without data it is difficult to tell if the script is correct to plot the "right" thing.

Comment: i have send you a mail sir in gmx.net

Comment: Please find another way to provide data!

Answer (score 0):

Plot your data first without setting a range, default is autorange or  `set xrange[*:*]`. Then you will see the region of interest.

And in your case this is not `set xrange[-6:4]` as you set, but maybe `set xrange[6:16]`.

[image]

[image]

Probably, you are looking for a script like this:

```
reset session

set key box font 'Helvetica, 12' top right noautotitle
set xlabel "E-E_f [eV]" font 'Helvetica, 20'
set xrange[-6:4]
set mxtics 2
set xzeroaxis lt 1 lc "black"
set ylabel "PDos(states/ev)" font 'Helvetica, 20'
set yrange[-10:10]
set yzeroaxis lt 1 dt 2 lw 1.5 lc "black"
set grid x,y

set label at first  0.25, first  5 "Spin-Up" font "Helvetica, 12"
set label at first  0.25, first -5 "Spin-Down" font "Helvetica, 12"
set label at first -0.5,  first  8 "Fermi-Level" font "Helvetica, 12" right
set arrow from first  0.75,  5.5 to 0.75, 7.5
set arrow from first  0.75, -5.5 to 0.75, -7.5
set arrow from first  -0.4, 8 to 0.0, 8

plot 'Co_d.dat' u ($1-12.6258):2     w l lc "green" ti "Co-4d", \
             '' u ($1-12.6258):(-$3) w l lc "green", \
     'Mn_d.dat' u ($1-12.6258):2     w l lc "red"   ti "Mn-4d", \
             '' u ($1-12.6258):(-$3) w l lc "red", \
     'Sb_p.dat' u ($1-12.6258):2     w l lc "#4169E1" ti "Sb-2p", \
             '' u ($1-12.6258):(-$3) w l lc "#4169E1"
```

[image]

Comment: or maybe you forgot to subtract some value, e.g. `...($1-12.6258):2...`

Comment: sir can i send you in google drive link because i have 3 data each of 3mb

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jKJrM5kkXx8RYCFY6QXc2gw4bQLt9QI6?usp=share_link

Comment: @BinayLimbu the graphs above should be these files. Please check your `xrange`.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/HTxvYdU.png
i get this output sir but one line is stilling missing and its far different than what i expect

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/FQDnMoQ.png
this is the similar result what i am expecting sir

Comment: @BinayLimbu please check the script in your previous question. I assume you have to plot the shifted column 1 versus column 2 and the shifted column 1 versus negative column 3. Something like `... u ($1-12.6258):2 ...` and `... u ($1-12.6258):(-$3) ...`.

Comment: sir i know only computational work but i have not much knowledge about gnuplot 
i have less duration for my project work so sir if you dont mind please once go through my data and generate script..i will learn gnuplot in my free time sir

Comment: @BinayLimbu I don't know anything about your calculations. You have to exactly tell me what you need to plot, which column, which offset, which sign, which range, etc.? See another guess in the modified answer.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/csUeKoT.png
this is my output sir still i am very far from what i expect i have send you above the final output what it should look like

Comment: i have send you a three file sir (co.dat,mn.dat,sb.dat) inside each file three is 3 column(energy,dosup,dosdown) where i have to plot x-axis(Energy-Ef)where Ef=12.6258 in my case and in y axis two column sir above y=0 dosup column and below y=0 dosdown column.range x[-6:4] with spacing 2 and yrange[-10:10]with spacing 5.And also i need at right top corner co-4d,mn-4d,sb-2pindex sir you can see in the graph i send you which i send as reference my graph should look similar to that

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr6JU.png

Comment: in case if my data doesnt fit with the range i send we can modified it sir its not compulsion

Comment: excuse me sir are you busy nowdays?
i am looking forward for your reponse sir

Comment: hello sir i have been stuck in same problem

Comment: @BinayLimbu is the problem finally solved with the modified answer?

Comment: no sir i am not getting smooth curve still

Comment: i want the graph like what i say in expected result sir

Comment: @BinayLimbu sorry, I don't know anymore what else to suggest. I guess I'm not able to help you.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/zGmdmzn.png

Comment: can you help me sir to get like this graph for single co atom

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yDOtYREhEbFyNr3jlVGZa2HqN2qmYCxo/view?usp=share_link